# TransferOwnership in Tezos

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, ligo

Is there an analog of transferOwnership in Tezos?

It looks like it's possible to make custom FA2 contract and change owner. Is this correct?

Looking for an authorative answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of owner of a smart contract in Tezos (anymore).

However, smart contracts can implement some custom logic to describe what managing them means (and typically store some admin address in their storage).

Answer (score -1):

Smart contracts are managed by the private key that created it. Transferring ownership means to transfer the private key to the new owner.

Comment: This message seems to imply that the blockchain treats the private key that created a contract in a special way. This is not true. Also, contracts can originate other contracts. Who would be the owner?

Comment: If I want to transfer tez from my multi-sig to a tz1, I must provide the contract's manager private key to create the bytes for signing. I must also provide the manager pk to do other management operations on the smart contract. Is that not ownership?

Comment: This is not related in general to who created the smart contract in the first place. This is simply a specific smart contract having the corresponding public key in its storage.